# Rails haml select helper default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

in haml I have this:

```
= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year",}
```

I want to set the default value of select year to 2020. How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess

```
= select_year Date.new(2020), {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"}
```